# How does boost::filesystem::unique_path() resolve the need in mkstemp analogue in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, temporary-files, boost-filesystem

An old [feature request](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/590) for Boost was requesting a feature similar to [mkstemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) POSIX function to be available in Boost.Filesystem. The issue is long closed as fixed, with the comment

> The unique_path() function in Version 3 addresses the problem.

But I fail to see how `unique_path` resolves the problem. It's basically the same as [tmpnam](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam): after the name has been generated and before actual file is created, another program may have created its file with the same name.

So how is it supposed to address the need in `mkstemp`?

Comment: No matter which file name you chose some another program may already use it. But since generating a file path that is reasonably unique is quite simple such clashes almost never occur.

Comment: Still, `unique_path` is considered enough of a security vulnerability to be rejected in C++17: https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2633 .

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the implementation (at least on *nix systems) could result in effectively calling `open` with `O_EXCL | O_CREAT`, which basically says "create the file, if it already exists, return an error.

So, an implementation could have an algorithm like this:

```
for(;;) {
    name = create_likley_unique_name();
    file = open(name, O_EXCL | O_CREAT, mode);
    if(valid(file)) {
        return file;
    }
}
```

This is of course just a guess, but I think it is a reasonable one. I have no idea if windows or osx have a comparable flag.

I think the key part of the "solution" on the page you linked is this part:

> The suggested fix is to (1) rename the function and (2) provide an
>   example of how to use the function safely with fstreams or even C I/O.
>   See below for proposed wording.

Where a proper example would something like what I just wrote, but using an equivalent c++ish API.

Note that in the thread they offer renaming the function to `generate_random_filename()`, which is more appropriate given that it is unpredictable, but not guaranteed to be unique. But also suggest a `create_unique_file()`, which would likely implement an algorithm similar to my example.

Comment: The only way though to get behavior similar to `O_EXCL` is available in C11 (and thus not in C++ before C++17): `fopen(testFileName,"w+x")`. It wasn't really available or even thinkable of 7 years ago when the feature request was closed.

Comment: Yea, I think the implementation of these functions would have to use non standard, system specific code. Which is acceptable for the the guys if the standard lib.